# Display html text from database in pdf generated with iTextSharp (Asp.Net Webform)

Tags: c#, replace, webforms, tags, itext

I have a problem to properly display an html text from database in pdf document which is generated with iTextSharp. I have a text editor in my project and my text is written to the database in this format (example)

```
<i><b>Hello World</b></i><br><p>What a <font color="#330022"> wonderful day!</p>
```

When I pass this text to the pdf document is displayed with the tags. I don't know how to get rid of them and actually pass the bold and italic text or the color. I have found only a solution for the `<br>` tag like this

```
 pdf.PreviewText = get.Rows[0]["text"].ToString();
 previewText = previewText.Replace("<br>", "\n\r");
```

for the `<b>` tag I have tried `previewText = previewText.Replace("<b>", ""\x1B|");` but it did not work for me. If anyone has an idea how can I replace these tags with escape characters which would work in c# I would be very grateful.

Comment: you should probably look into xmlworker

Comment: @andré-lemos do you have any idea how should I use it? I tried like this but it did not work. XMLWorkerHelper worker = XMLWorkerHelper.GetCSS(previewText);

Comment: well, you should be using [pdfHTML](https://itextpdf.com/products/itext-7/convert-html-css-to-pdf-pdfhtml), which is the spiritual successor of xmlworker, but it looks like the 3rd example [here](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it5kb/examples/xml-worker-examples) might be what you're after

Comment: @andré-lemos as I could see, that example is for parsing an entire HTML file. I need to parse a string from database. It is written with the tags as a string. I don't have problem with showing the text on pdf file, but the formatting is not working. Bold or italic for example.

Comment: you can use [convertToElements](https://api.itextpdf.com/pdfHTML/java/4.0.4/com/itextpdf/html2pdf/HtmlConverter.html#convertToElements-java.lang.String-) so you can take a string of Text and convert it to a PDF element.

Comment: just realized you're C#. here's the same page: [convertToElements](https://api.itextpdf.com/pdfHTML/dotnet/4.0.4/classi_text_1_1_html2pdf_1_1_html_converter.html#a9cf6ee51d8ca2441f0ccc9f80e67f9ed) for C#.

Comment: Yes that worker perfectly, only Unicode symbols are not displayed good, they appear as question marks, and I have some bullets escaped with \u2022 and some other symbols which don't appear on the pdf document @andré-lemos